# How can I use the "s///" operator in order to change number of values?

Tags: perl, substitution

I have a file that contains:

```
foo1 = 1

foo2 =  2

foo3 =    8

.
.
.
```

I need to replace only the values (1,2,8...) in that file with part of a memory hash values, the ones with the same keys (foo1 -> 33,foo2 -> 44,foo3...) How can I change it using the "s///" operator? If there is other elegant ways to conduct it I'll be happy to know.

Thanks for any help,

Yohad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way

```
%hash = ("foo1"=>33,"foo2" => 44,"foo3"=>99);
while (<>){
  chomp;
  ( $one , $two ) = split /\s+=\s+/, $_;
  print "$one = $hash{$one} \n"
}
```

Comment: You might want to clarify that to actually save the new value, you need to do `$hash{$one} = $two;`

Comment: actually, i thought OP wants to update his file. That's why i use print instead so that OP can redirect to new file on the command line. (of course another way is to use open() with write ), anyway.....

Comment: You're right. I got the OP's request backward. I thought he wanted to update a saved `%hash` based on the records in the file, but I now see that you're right about what he wants.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer, it's quite understandable! But my input file follow like this: foo1_____ =_______ 1 foo2__ =_ 2 it has unexpected spaces that disturb finding my hash key. so what shell I write in the split function in order to ignore to space characters ?

Answer (score 6):

```
my %new_values = ( foo1 => 33, ... );
$data =~ s{^(?<key>\w+) = \K(?<old_value>.+)$}
          {$new_values{$+{key}}}gem;
```

The key is the "e" flag which lets you run code to determine the replacement.  The `(?<...>)` syntax increases readability, and the `\K` allows us to match the entire line but only replace the value area.  The "g" flag repeats the substitution as many times as possible, and the "m" flag makes `^...$` match a line instead of the entire string.  (The `g` and `m` will probably be unnecessary if you split the lines before application of the regexp.)

Comment: Why "{}" instead of "//"? And what's "+" in "$+{key}"? I found the example very interesting, but I found it difficult to read, and I know what you are doing. This answer could really benefit from an extensive revision for dummies. :-)

Comment: @ Daniel: it's a named capture. `$+{key}` refers back to the item captured (and named) in `(?<key>\w+)`. See the named captures section here: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html

Comment: @Jrockway: I'm not sure I would say anything about it has "increased readability", but +1 for giving me a reason to reread `perldoc perlre`. Very cool

Comment: Note that \K and (?<name>...) require 5.10 or higher.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one

```
%h = ("foo1"=>3, "foo2"=>5);
while (<>)
{
    #Substitute value according to expression on right hand side
    s/(\w+) = .*/$1 . " = ". $h{$1}/e;
    print;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

s/regexPattern/replacementPattern/flags

"I am a string!"

s/\sam/'s/g

"I's a  string!"

http://gnosis.cx/publish/programming/regular_expressions.html

I really can't understand what you're doing based on the descriptoin. Can you provide sample input and output?

Comment: input file: [name][spaceeeeeee] = [spacee][number]
output file: [name] = [$hash{name}]